# Does Xcode4 have automatic implementation creation feature?

Tags: iphone, xcode, visual-assist-x

I'm so used to Visual assist X and one of my favorite feature was automatic implementation creation feature.

You put the cursor on the any interface in header file and you run the feature, it creates empty function in your cpp file. And the cursor is ready inside the function in cpp file.

I wish I could use similar feature in Xcode4. There's Refactor menu but I couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: not this is not posible in XCode4 you have to write a method in .m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends on where you create the action or outlet. If you create them in the header file, then no they are not automatically implemented. However if you create them by using the Assistant editor and dragging a link directly to the header file, then the Action/Outlet is created in the header and implementation files.

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow, you captures those images just for this question? I've got the answer and another tip. thanks ;)